# How do I format MongoDB-style table data for Highcharts using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, charts, highcharts

I have some data like so:

```json
[{
    "displayname": "Someone",
    "artistname": "Artist",
    "songtitle": "Title",
    "difficultyid": 5,
    "scoreactual": 642.5,
    "scorepossible": 658.5,
    "id": 26324,
    "timeachieved": 1455948669
}, {
    "displayname": "Someone",
    "artistname": "Another Artist",
    "songtitle": "Another Song",
    "difficultyid": 5,
    "scoreactual": 547.5,
    "scorepossible": 574.5,
    "id": 26324,
    "timeachieved": 1455948669
}, {
    "displayname": "SomeoneElse",
    "artistname": "Another Artist",
    "songtitle": "Another Song",
    "difficultyid": 6,
    "scoreactual": 544,
    "scorepossible": 574.5,
    "id": 26323,
    "timeachieved": 1455948526
}]
```

When I worked with DataGrid, I remember being able to format each JSON object with a few callbacks and object properties; although, in using Highcharts, I've found I had to do a lot of complicated data manipulation to turn this data into something usable by Highcharts.

Final data structure would be something like this:

```js
{
    categoryData: ['Title', 'Another Song']
    seriesData: [{
        name: 'Someone'
        data: [642.5, 547.5]
    }, {
        name: 'SomeoneElse'
        data: [0, 544]
    }]
}
```

Here's the code I wrote to generically do the conversion for any 3 data selectors (I believe this code is far too complex):

```js
export function getSeriesDataFromTableRows(selectors) {
    const { tableRows, nameSelector, categorySelector, dataSelector, cb } = selectors

    let nameSelections = {},
        categorySelections = {},
        categoryCount = 0,
        seriesData = [],
        categoryData = []

    for (let tableRow of tableRows) {
        let name = tableRow[nameSelector],
            category = tableRow[categorySelector]

        !nameSelections[name]
            && (nameSelections[name] = [])
        nameSelections[name].push(tableRow)

        !categorySelections[category] && (categorySelections[category] = categoryCount++)
    }

    for (let category of Object.keys(categorySelections)) {
        let categoryIndex = categorySelections[category]
        categoryData[categoryIndex] = category
    }

    for (let name of Object.keys(nameSelections)) {
        let tableRowSelections = nameSelections[name],
            data = []

        for (let tableRow of tableRowSelections) {
            let category = tableRow[categorySelector],
                categoryIndex = categorySelections[category],
                dataSelection = tableRow[dataSelector]

            data[categoryIndex] = cb ? cb(dataSelection) : dataSelection
        }

        for (let categoryIndex = 0; categoryIndex < categoryCount; categoryIndex++) {
            !data[categoryIndex] && (data[categoryIndex] = 0)
        }

        seriesData.push({
            name,
            data
        })
    }

    return {
        seriesData,
        categoryData
    }
}
```

Is there a better method of formatting this data in JavaScript for Highcharts? Or is there a tool I can hook into to do this for me?

Comment: Why don't you  do it server-side using the aggregation framework?

Comment: What's the aggregation framework?

Comment: [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: I'm actually hooking into an old MySQL DB and querying it manually. This is how the data is coming back like how I'd see when using MongoDB. The Aggregation framework looks amazing if I could use it. Currently all the data is coming in the MySQL DB via PHP from another server and converting the whole DB would be a huge task.